# Bimetallic Thermostat

Tags: thermostat

I have a [One Shot Type Thermostat](http://www.wako-clinac.co.jp/product_en/b-2_cs-7ta-35_en/) ***CS-7TA-35 195 6103*** that i've removed from a laser printer's fuser unit.

There was a paper jam within the fuser unit which I assume tripped this "one shot" by metalic strip.

1) when the device reaches its operating temperature, does it act like a conventional fuse and go open circuit? It's open circuit now.

2) Is there a way to reset the device, or do I need a new one?

3) Am I correct that this device will operate at 180 degrees celsius?

Comment: I would normally refer to that kind of device as a "thermal fuse" because it is not resettable. Once its 'trip' condition has occurred it needs to be replaced.

Comment: "One Shot" gives you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to reset the device.

There is an oblong piece of mettle set in a round space. This allows one to get a small piece of wire (none flexible, i.e. a pin) under the metallic strip and snap it up; it then becomes loose ish.

Ive tested it with a lighter and it clicks then becomes open circuit.

I guess it's a one shot in reality, because it's not designed to be reset.

This quick fix will get you going until you can get a replacement part.